# Not able to print the array inside the array in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

### Reading JSON in AngularJS

I am trying to learn AngularJS, but I've hit a small snag when it comes to retrieving JSON-data.

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-cs/chFZiN24E4KMATLdqdvsezGxaGsi4hLGOzlXwp5UZB1LY//20VyM2taTB4QvJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-uefMccjFJAIv6A+rW+L4AHf99KvxDjWSu1z9VI8SKNVmz4sk7buKt/6v9KI65qnm" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ODataResources/1.0.25/odataresources.min.js"></script>
</head>

<script>
  var app = angular.module('links', []);
  app.controller('feedLinks', function($scope, $http) {
    const BASE_URL = 'http://services.odata.org/V3/OData/OData.svc/'
    $http.get(BASE_URL)
      .then(function(response) {
        $scope.rawdata = response.data; //array with two elements - one link, and an array with data
      });
  });
</script>

<body>
  <div class="container main-container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col menu">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
          <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
           <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
            <ul>
              <div ng-app="links" ng-controller="feedLinks">
                <li ng-repeat="element in rawdata">
                  {{ element }}
                  <a class="nav-link" href="{{ element.url }}">{{ element.name }}</a>
                </li>
              </div>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Instead of getting an array with data which I can create links from, I am getting an array with two elements, a link and another array. And I am not able to print the array inside the array... Any pointers would be appreciated.

---

On the telephone now, here is a screenshot:

[image]

Comment: can you provide sample of array you are getting?

Comment: you can also access element by index. e.g element[0]

Comment: Provide us the response you are getting

Comment: On the telephone now, here is a screenshot: http://imgur.com/gallery/Jph7J7y

Comment: What I tried was getting the element by ID and using that as "raw data", instead of the initial array. No error messages was given in console, but no data was showing. However, Ashokan Sivapragasam's suggestion worked like a charm - it is working as intended now! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-cs/chFZiN24E4KMATLdqdvsezGxaGsi4hLGOzlXwp5UZB1LY//20VyM2taTB4QvJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-uefMccjFJAIv6A+rW+L4AHf99KvxDjWSu1z9VI8SKNVmz4sk7buKt/6v9KI65qnm" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ODataResources/1.0.25/odataresources.min.js"></script>
  </head>

  <script>
```

```js
    var app = angular.module('links', []);
    app.controller('feedLinks', function($scope, $http) {
        const BASE_URL = 'http://services.odata.org/V3/OData/OData.svc/'
        $http.get(BASE_URL)
        .then(function(response) {
            $scope.rawdata = response.data; //array with two elements - one link, and an array with data
        });
    });
```

```html
  </script>

  <body>
        <div class="container main-container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col menu">
                    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
                        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
                        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button"
                                data-toggle="collapse"
                                data-target="#navbarNav"
                                aria-controls="navbarNav"
                                aria-expanded="false"
                                aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                        </button>
                        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
                        <ul>
                            <div ng-app="links" ng-controller="feedLinks">
                                <li ng-repeat="element in rawdata.value">
                                    <a class="nav-link" href="{{ element }}"> 
                                     {{ element.name }}
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                            </div>
                        </ul>
                      </div>
                    </nav>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Will try when I get home. Thanks.